# Ruby keep occurance count in ordered data structure

Tags: ruby, sorting, data-structures

I have a ruby script that keeps a count of the number of times a particular object appears - it doesn't work because every data structure I've found sorts by **key**, or when it is sorted by value it returns an **array or arrays**

I'm wondering what the best way to go about storing this data is..

I just have a bunch of objects, with ID's from a database, as I loop through a given set of data, I want to keep track of how many times I use a certain object, so I need to increment the **times used** for the given object.

Basically what I'm doing is create a priority queue of sorts, where I want to assure that each objects gets used just as many times as the other objects, so I sort the list by occurrence, and use the objects with fewest occurrences first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is where I ended up.. with a working solution. I used a normal array as a priority queue of sorts, so rather than having the ID of the object be the key, and the value how many times it's been accessed, I simple am storing the object ID in an array.

With an array of ID's, when it comes time to 'increment' I simply delete it from the array, and push it back on the end of the array - since arrays have 'implied' indexes the preserve order.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, I'd use the [SortedSet](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/SortedSet.html) class + a custom class to do three things: implement `#eql?`, `hash`, and `<=>`. It'd look like this:

```
class WeightedEntry
  attr_accessor :weight, :object

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
    @weight = 1
  end

  def hash
    self.object.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self.equal?(other) || self.object.equal?(other.object)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    self.weight <=> other.weight
  end

  def incr
    @weight += 1
  end
end
```

However, looking at the source code (`set.rb`), this class is only efficient if you also have `rbtree` somewhere in your load path. So you'll want to make sure to [get that as well](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-rbtree/).

Your next problem is that modifying the weight won't rebalance `rbtree`. I am not sure how to solve that.

Alas, this is where my data structure-fu gives out and [just use Redis](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), but perhaps this will enlighten you to discover a solution.

Comment: Testing Redis.. I spent a bit of time looking at https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms for a solution but found nothing.. I may be scrapping my entire process and just using a priority queue from that gem though..

Comment: Yea, its an interesting problem, the built-in data structure definitely don't handle this well. That algorithms gem looks useful & awesome! Redis might work structurally, but the problem is getting the object back in Rubyland. You're probably better off using that gem...

Comment: Update: you can find objects by object_id using `ObjectSpace._id2ref`, so if you stored object IDs in Redis, you could find the instantiated objects this way. Given its an underscore method, I guess it's not recommended to use this, but it seems to work.

Comment: yea.. I can't believe this isnt used more often.. starting to think I should reconsider my logic haha